# False review count

Tags: discussion

Immediately after reaching 2k, the suggested edits count showing 10

[image: Imgur]

But the actual suggested edit count:

[image: Imgur]

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nwWF.jpg) is the total image.

Comment: Your full picture link seems dead. Other than that, yup, I'm affected by this too.

Comment: That's the mod tools count, not just suggested edits. On Ask Ubuntu it's 380 atm. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#230726 also it's heavily cached.

Comment: @r3bl thanks, let me correct =)